# Win.blit argument one must be surface not tuple, but its a running sprite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've got one sprite and the proper running left and right sprites. I have a class for my player but whenever i try to run left or right I get an error that says:

> win.blit(walkLeft,[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
>   TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not tuple'''

I've tried to put the surface there but that doesn't seem to change anything either. Sorry for this basic of a question, I'm extremely new to python. Here's the full code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screenwidth = 500
screenheight = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenwidth, screenheight))
pygame.display.set_caption('First Game')


bkg = pygame.image.load('2.jpg')
char1 = pygame.image.load('guy.png')
char1 = pygame.transform.scale(char1, (100, 100))
walkLeft = pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'), pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'),
pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png'), pygame.image.load('R10.png'), pygame.image.load('R11.png'), pygame.image.load('R12.png')
walkRight = pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'), pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'),
pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png'), pygame.image.load('L10.png'), pygame.image.load('L11.png'), pygame.image.load('L12.png')
GameO = pygame.image.load('GO.jpg')


clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x ,y, width, height):


        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.GameOver = False
        self.vel = 5
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
    def draw(self, win):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 36:
            self.walkCount = 0
        if self.left:
            win.blit(walkLeft,[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        elif self.right:
            win.blit(walkRight,[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            win.blit(char1, (self.x, self.y))


def redrawgamewindow():
    win.blit(bkg, (0, 0))
    man.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

man = player(250, 400, 100, 100)
run = True
while run:
    #Setting fps
    clock.tick(36)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
    #Getting keys pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
        man.x -= man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.vel - man.width:
        man.x += man.vel
        man.left = False
        man.right = True

    else:
        man.left = False
        man.right = False
        man.walkCount = 0

    redrawgamewindow()
```

Comment: It's a simple typo: `walkLeft[self.walkCount // 3]` rather than `walkLeft,[self.walkCount // 3]` (there is a comma where none should be)

Comment: Thanks wow it was that easy

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. There is a comma where it shouldn't be (`walkRight,[self.walkCount // 3]`):

<s>`win.blit(walkRight,[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))`</s>

```py
win.blit(walkRight.[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
```